# Codeigniter Email with SMTP is displaying weird format

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, codeigniter-3

I have an HTML message as below.

```
<p>This is a bank account number *********0205</p>
<p><b>This is a test email.</b></p>
<p>This is my email me@me.com</p>
<p>This is a link <a href='https://xxxxxx.uslogistics.com/images/logo_big.png'>https://xxxxxx.uslogistics.com/images/logo_big.png</a><p>
```

I want to send that message via SMTP. The host used is smtp.office365.com

I'm using Codeignitor, when I send my email without SMTP the email I receive is displaying well, see below (image and code)

```
<?php 
$this->load->library('email');
$body = "<p><b>This is a test email.</b></p><p>This is my email me@me.com</p><p>This is a link <a href='https://xxxxxx.uslogistics.com/images/logo_big.png'>https://xxxxxx.uslogistics.com/images/logo_big.png</a><p>";
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$this->email->clear(TRUE);
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from("no-reply@domain.com", "No Replay");
$this->email->to("myownemail@hotmail.fr");
$this->email->subject("Test");
$this->email->message($body);
$this->email->send();
```

[image]

When I use SMTP I get a wired email (see image and code below)

```
$this->load->library('email');
$body = "<p><b>This is a test email.</b></p><p>This is my email me@me.com</p><p>This is a link <a href='https://xxxxxx.uslogistics.com/images/logo_big.png'>https://xxxxxx.uslogistics.com/images/logo_big.png</a><p>";
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.office365.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = ""; //Here I put the SMTP username
$config['smtp_pass'] =""; //Here I put the SMTP password
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$this->email->clear(TRUE);
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from("", "No Replay");//Here I put the SMTP username as email.
$this->email->to("myownemail@hotmail.fr");
$this->email->subject("Test");
$this->email->message($body);
$this->email->send();
```

[image]

This is just a simple HTML, if I use tables, they are all relaced with wired text.

To make sure it is about codeignitor, I used PHPMailer (a new project no CI) and when I send the same HTML email with SMTP or  without I get the correct email received every time.

Here is my PHPMailer code for SMTP:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = '';//Here I put the SMTP username.
    $mail->Password = '';//Here I put the SMTP password.
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->setFrom('');//Here I put the SMTP username as email.
    $mail->addAddress('myownemail@hotmail.fr');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = '';
    $mail->Body    = "<p><b>This is a test email.</b></p><p>This is my email me@me.com</p><p>This is a link <a href='https://xxxxxx.uslogistics.com/images/logo_big.png'>https://xxxxxx.uslogistics.com/images/logo_big.png</a><p>";
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried, to save your body in PHP var, then assign it to `$mail->body`

Comment: You mean in CI or PHPMailer?

Comment: If you mean in PHPMailer, I just did it and it is still displaying emails correctly.

Comment: Looks like a bug in CI's mailer. Those `=` chars indicate it's using a quoted-printable transfer encoding, but if it messes up other aspects of encoding, it can leave artifacts like that. Are you using latest CI?

Comment: yes latest version 3.1.7

Answer (score 0):

This email.php config finally works for me:

```
config= array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp', 
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.office365.com', 
    'smtp_port' => '587', 
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx@xxx.xx', 
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxx', 
    'smtp_crypto' => 'tls', 
    'charset' => 'utf-8', 
    'crlf' => "\r\n", 
    'newline' => "\r\n", 
    'mailtype' => 'html');
```